# Why do my bootstrap buttons design differs from default

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.5. When creating a btn-primary in my html like:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Button Text</button>
```

i'm getting a different result as stated on the [bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons). I'm talking about the gradient that the button has when I'm using bootstraps button inside my page. When expecting the the element with Chrome's Dev-Console I can see that the gradient comes from the theme.less file and of course I can manipulate it. But shouldn't it be by default like on the bootstrap website?

[image]

Comment: Is the `theme.less` part of Bootstrap? Otherwise you have to remove it from that file.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that removig the

```
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

tag from my html-head helped already.

I've installed bootstrap via bower. Would be nice if one could "opt-out" the theme via config instead of deleting the theme files or the link tag in head manually.